# Rendering json Object with express and jade - Can't access json fields

Tags: json, node.js, express, pug

Relevant Express part of my node application:

```
/*Route to Product Views*/
app.get('/product/:id', function(req, res){
        Product.find({_id: req.params.id}, function (error, data) {
                if(error){
                        console.log(error);
                } else {
                        console.log("DATA :" + data); //correct json object
                        res.render('product',{
                                title: 'Product Template',
                                result: data
                                }
                        );
                }
        });

});
```

Jade Template:

```
!!! 5
html
  head
    title #{title}
  body
    h1 #{result.name}
    h2 #{result.unitprice}
    p.
       #{result.description}
    h3 #{result}
```

So if I vistit http://myhost.com/product/51fa8402803244fb12000001 all I see is the output of *h3 #{result}*, which is:

```
[{ 
__v: 0, 
_id: 51fa8402803244fb12000001, 
description: 'Awesome stuff you really need', 
discontinued: false, 
name: 'Some product', 
unitprice: 5.99 
}]
```

Using JSON.stringify makes no difference except that *h3 #{result}* returns "stringified" JSON.
How to correctly access the fields of the json string?

Comment: Brother, if `result` is a single-document array, shouldn't you be using `result[0].name`, `result[0].unitprice`? What does `console.log` print?

Comment: Thanks Bro, it works like that if JSON.stringify() is _not_ used!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output of your DB query returns the result as an array, so you need to send as data[0] to the product template, so that you can access directly the values else you need to access as result[0].name etc.

```
/*Route to Product Views*/
app.get('/product/:id', function(req, res){
        Product.find({_id: req.params.id}, function (error, data) {
                if(error){
                        console.log(error);
                } else {
                        console.log("DATA :" + data[0]); //correct json object
                        res.render('product',{
                                title: 'Product Template',
                                result: data[0]
                                }
                        );
                }
        });

})
```

Jade Template:

```
!!! 5
html
  head
    title #{title}
  body
    - product = typeof(result) != 'undefined' ? result : { }
    h1 #{product.name}
    h2 #{product.unitprice}
    p.
       #{product.description}
    h3 #{product}
```

Comment: Even if the question has been answered before by c.P.u, your answer is correct ;)

Comment: Hey how to access the product in the client side javascript ?